# Unix Shell - Removing special newline characters

Tags: shell, unix, sed

We are receiving a file that is delimited into rows with the \(newline) and columns with the \(tab) character.

When there is a manual newline present in one of the "fields" of the file, it comes in as a special newline with two backslashes (\\newline).

To remove the special tabs \(tab), we are using this sed command, which works correctly:

```
sed "s/$(printf '\\\\\t')/ /g"
```

The corresponding command for newlines, however does not:

```
sed "s/$(printf '\\\\\n')/ /g"
```

It does not remove the \n, only the backslash before it. Is there special handling that needs to be done to remove \(newline)?

Clarification: normal newlines are formatted like this:

```
\(newline)
```

Wheras the special characters that need removal are

```
\\(newline)
```

Comment: Does the file have the string "\\n" in the line, or there is really a newline character after a backslash (breaking the single line of data into two lines).

Comment: I believe it is actually `\\\(newline char)'

Comment: It appears as two lines: first one ending with \ and then the next line.

Comment: Your notation is not very clear - how many backslashes are there before the actual newline? Please post `echo -e` command that will produce test output of exactly what you want to remove. Is it `echo -e '\\\n'` or `echo -e '\\\\\n'`, or `echo -e '\\n'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
echo -e 'hello\\\nthere' | perl -ne 's/\\\n/ /; print'
```

It would be difficult (but probably possible) to do this in `sed`, because `sed` processes input line by line, and your data is broken into multiple lines. This `perl` one-liner processes the input line by line, and since it treats the newline character as part of the line, it can perform a substitution with space, which I think has the effect that you want.

Or if you prefer `awk`:

```
echo -e 'hello\\\nthere' | awk '{ if (gsub(/\\$/, " ")) printf; else print }'
```

At first I suspected your "special newline" character is just the string `\\n` like in the output of this command:

```
echo 'hello\\nthere'
```

You can replace the string `\\n` with a space like this:

```
echo 'hello\\nthere' | sed -e 's/\\\\n/ /g'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! The final code I'm using is this:

perl -pi -e 's/\\\n/ _ /g' datafile.tsv

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr (translate)` command as well to do this, like

```
tr '\n' ' ' < inputfile.txt
```

**EdIT:**   In that case use it like

```
tr '\\\n' ' ' < inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Yes, but I only want to remove newline characters with 2 backslashes before them